# Redis multi Key or multi Hash field

Tags: redis

I have about 300k row data like this **Session:Hist:[account]**

*Session:Hist:100000*

*Session:Hist:100001*

*Session:Hist:100002*

*.....*

Each have 5-10 childs **[session]:[time]**

*b31c2a43-e61b-493a-b8d4-ff0729fe89de:1846971068807*

*5552daa2-c9f6-4635-8a7c-6f027b4aa1a3:1846971065461*

*.....*

I have 2 options:

1. Using Hash, key is **Session:Hist:[account]**, field is **[session]**, value is **[time]**
2. Using Hash flat all account, key is **Session:Hist**, field is **[account]:[session]**, value is **[time]**

My Redis have 1 master, 4-5 Slave, using to store & push session (about 300k *5 in 2h) every days, and clear at end of day!

So the question is which options is better for performance (faster sync master-slave/smaller memory/faster for huge request), thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you consider using the JSON module? See - https://redis.io/docs/stack/json/

Comment: Which access patterns are most common / important? i.e. you might only need to get full map for each `account` or you might only need `time` for a specific `session` in a specific `account`.

Comment: @GuyKorland thank you, i dont need JSON in my data

Comment: @TasosP. i need check session of account exist, and time if it exist, with both struct i can get it easy and fast.
i just want to compare which options is better, faster/smaller memory/better for master-slave sync with huge data in a small time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the two options mentioned, option #2 is less optimal.

According to [official Redis documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/data-types-tutorial/#hashes):

> It is worth noting that small hashes (i.e., a few elements with small values) are encoded in special way in memory that make them very memory efficient.

More details [here](https://redis.io/docs/reference/optimization/memory-optimization/#using-hashes-to-abstract-a-very-memory-efficient-plain-key-value-store-on-top-of-redis).

So having one huge hash with key `Session:Hist` would affect memory consumption. It would also affect clustering (sharding) since you would have one hash (hot-spot) located on one instance which would get hammered.

Option #1 does not suffer from the problems mentioned above. As long as you have many well-distributed (i.e. all accounts have similar count of sessions vs a few accounts being dominant with huge amount of sessions) hashes keyed as `Session:Hist:[account]`.

If, however, there is a possibility for uneven distribution of sessions into accounts, you could try (and measure) the efficiency of option 1a:

- Key: `Session:Hist:[account]:[session - last two characters]`
- field: `[session's last two characters]`
- value: `[time]`

Example:

- Key: `Session:Hist:100000:b31c2a43-e61b-493a-b8d4-ff0729fe89`
- field: `de`
- value: `1846971068807`

This way, each hash will only contain *up to* 256 fields (assuming last 2 characters of session are hex, all possible combinations would be 256). This would be optimal if `redis.conf` defines `hash-max-zipmap-entries 256`.

Obviously option 1a would require some modifications in your application but with proper bench-marking (i.e. memory savings) you could decide if it's worth the effort.

Comment: thank you for your clearly and exciting answear, i'll keep option #1 and try your options 1a as you suggest when i have time :)